# Ukrainian language rules to start words with capital letter?

Tags: граматика, orthography, велика-мала-літера

In English exists pretty wide range of special [rules](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/caps0.htm) to start specific words from the capital letters. There are days of the week, months of the year, holidays (Monday, Friday; June, July; New Year), countries, languages & nationalities, religions(Ukraine; Japanese; Buddhism), etc.

What about Ukrainian language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ukrainian language usually only *Proper nouns* are capitalized.
Every other nouns are not capitalized.

You can also find more information about this and about exceptions in these resources:

[Ukrainian Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

[Site litopys](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38)

Comment: Я б додав посилання на правопис: http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38
у мене слалося враження (я лише швидко проглянув, можу помилятися), що з наведених посилань більшість просто скопіювали текст з правопису, крім http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/224.htm Можливо, варто обмежитися правописом і цим посиланням, якщо в решті немає додаткової корисної інформації.

Answer (score 6):

Ukrainian in general is less demanding in matter of capitalization than English. For example, the following are NOT capitalized in Ukrainian (despite they are in English):

- Days of the week (понеділок, вівторок)
- Months of the year (січень, лютий)
- Languages (українська, англійська)
- Nationalities (українець, британець)
- Religions (православний, католик)
- Adjectives from proper name (аристотелівський, гедоністичний)
- -isms from proper names (ніцшеанство, епікуреїзм)
- *The list isn't exhaustive, feel free to extend it!*

Still many of other cases — e.g. people and pet names, place names (toponyms: countries, streets, etc), organizations, holidays —  require capitalization.